# "maven-shade-plugin" not found

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

For some odd reason it's saying "maven-shade-plugin" not found. I really have no clue why it's exactly "can't be found" I was hoping you guys would have a solution. I'm also on **Java 8**

Picture
http://puu.sh/k8hbI/dca0cf4cc8.png

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>legacycitizens</groupId>
    <artifactId>RLCitizens</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>techcable-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.techcable.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.techcable</groupId>
            <artifactId>npclib</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>net.techcable.npclib</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>legacycitizens.libs.npclib</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: maven-shade-plugin is available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20a%3A%22maven-shade-plugin%22)

Comment: Try to run from command line first.